# ExtJS: Unable to call findById on a toolbar added by apply()

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a page with a toolbar on it, that is added through apply like so (abridged code, lots of irrelevant stuff in the original):

```
var obj = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    initComponent:function(){
        Ext.apply(this,{
            layout:'card',
            itemId:'contactDetails',
            border:false,
            activeItem:0,
            tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
                items:[{text:'New'},{text:'Edit',id:'editButton'}]
            })
        });
        obj.superclass.initComponent.apply(this);

     }, load:function() {
         this.tbar.findById('editButton').toggle(false); //Javascript error here about findById not being a function.
     }
   });
```

The above may not be syntactically correct either. It is in my code (at least to the extent that no javascript errors aside from the big one are thrown.)

Comment: Has it rendered at the point you are calling the load function?

Comment: Yes, load is triggered by another button on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you don't have to override initComponent just to provide default configs.  This will work the same way and is simpler:

```
var obj = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    layout:'card',
    itemId:'contactDetails',
    border:false,
    activeItem:0,
    tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
        items:[{text:'New'},{text:'Edit',id:'editButton'}]
    })
});
```

(Scratch my previous answer, I misread your code.)

This might also solve your problem -- since you are overriding initComponent in your code, you must call the superclass initComponent within your method or else things will not work.  When overriding initComponent your code you should be doing this:

```
initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this,{
        layout:'card',
        itemId:'contactDetails',
        border:false,
        activeItem:0,
        tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
            items:[{text:'New'},{text:'Edit',id:'editButton'}]
        })
    });
    obj.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Also, are you actually overriding the existing `Panel.load()` method for some reason? Or are you trying to add some different functionality and chose an existing method name by mistake?

**EDIT**: Should have noticed this earlier, but the `tbar` config is not available after render as a valid property.  From the docs for tbar: "To access the top toolbar after render, use [getTopToolbar](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Panel&member=getTopToolbar)"

Comment: Hmm... This is actually inherited code, and I have 0 ExtJS experience, so I was hoping for a really easy solution.  I think, though, that I have both of your simple solutions covered, I just left them out.  I'll update my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Oh and I honestly do not know what is going on with the load method - I do know that it isn't run until called though.

Comment: Shouldn't you call the superclass *after* defining the stuff with Ext.apply ?

Comment: Yes, in this case the superclass call should come after (it doesn't always matter though).  Even better, don't do that at all and follow my first example.